# Como achar "buracos" em tabelas SQL Server?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela com uma coluna `id` (chave primária, auto incremento de valor 1).

Minha aplicação **não** permite que as linhas sejam excluídas, portanto o esperado da *query*

```
SELECT id FROM tbl ORDER BY id ASC
```

seria isso:

```
id
---
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
...
```

Entretanto, algumas linhas foram excluídas por algum motivo, seja por que meu usuário manipulou a tabela fora da minha aplicação ou o banco de dados está corrompido. O motivo do sumiço dessas linhas não me interessa no momento.

Executando a mesma *query* do início, meu resultado não é o que eu espero:

```
id
---
1
2
3
6
10
12
8870
...
```

Como eu posso escrever uma *query* para achar esses espaços? Preciso encontrar aonde esses *gaps* iniciam, no caso do resultado acima, preciso extrair algo do tipo:

```
id
---
3
```

Pois foi a partir do `id` de valor 3 em que os espaços começam.

Comment: Qual `database` estás utilizando?

Comment: SQL Server. Alterei o título.

Comment: Só por curiosidade, qual seria o motivo disso?

Comment: Podes anexar o `DDL` dessa tabela?

Comment: Na lógica do meu aplicativo, o usuário não pode excluir linhas, somente inativá-las. Alguns usuários tem excluido linhas manualmente. Outro motivo seria identificar alguns bancos que estão corrompidos, que tem esses gaps por algum motivo.

Comment: É só não deletar os valores da tabela

Comment: Isto se refere ao ordenamento de um SELECT? É em uma query? Ou esta falando que esta aparecendo assim em algum software gerenciador? Pode explicar aonde exatamente esta aparecendo assim?

Comment: Não se refere à ordenação. As linhas faltantes foram excluídas ou o banco foi corrompido.

Comment: @vnbrs tá dificil de entender, na pergunta você adicionou `...`, presumi que havia mais coisas, agora se for corrompido então o problema é bem diferente. Isto é quando faz um SELECT, correto? Então simplesmente tente isto: `SELECT id FROM minha_tabela ORDER BY id;` e diga se aparece "falhado" ou não.

Comment: Exemplifiquei na pergunta. Tenho tabelas com mais de 100 mil registros, é difícil identificar no olho :P

Comment: Então o que quer dizer é que os "buracos existem" de fato, e você apenas quer identificar quais IDs estão sobrando sem registro? Ou você quer saber porque estes IDs supostamente sumiram?

Comment: Quero saber em que ID começou o gap. A pergunta não é sobre o motivo de esses IDs terem sumido.

Comment: @vnbrs sim, agora começou a clarear, é que você disse, "não deveria", isso leva a um entendimento totalmente diferente. Pelo seu ultimo comentário o que você quer saber é em qual o *"primeiro"* ID aonde começou estes "buracos", ao menos foi o que levou a entender.

Comment: É só chamar a tabela de "asfalto".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Encontrando os intervalos

Seguem duas soluções eficientes, obtidas no artigo [Solving Gaps and Islands with Enhanced Window Functions](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions).

A primeira solução atende a várias versões do SQL Server.

```
-- código #1
SELECT col1 + 1 AS rangestart, 
       (SELECT MIN(B.col1)   
          FROM dbo.T1 AS B
          WHERE B.col1 > A.col1) - 1 AS rangeend 
  FROM dbo.T1 AS A
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                      FROM dbo.T1 AS B
                      WHERE B.col1 = A.col1 + 1)
        AND col1 < (SELECT MAX(col1) FROM dbo.T1);
```

No código #1, substitua `col1` pelo nome da coluna que contém a numeração e `T1` pelo nome da tabela.

---

Há outra sugestão, mais eficiente ainda, que funciona a partir da versão 2012 (inclusive) do SQL Server. Utiliza a *window function* [LEAD()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql).

```
-- código #2
WITH C AS (
SELECT col1 AS cur, LEAD(col1) OVER(ORDER BY col1) AS nxt
  FROM dbo.T1
)
SELECT cur + 1 AS rangestart, nxt - 1 AS rangeend
  FROM C
  WHERE nxt - cur > 1;
```

No código #2, substitua `col1` pelo nome da coluna que contém a numeração e `T1` pelo nome da tabela.

---

> Qual a causa dos intervalos?

Os motivos podem ser vários. Para intervalos pequenos deve-se procurar a causa no aplicativo e nos acessos realizados diretamente à tabela pelos usuários. Para intervalos maiores (geralmente múltiplos de 1000), uma possibilidade é que a causa esteja diretamente ligada à forma como o [IDENTITY](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property) é implementado em SQL Server. Na própria documentação consta “*SQL Server might cache identity values for performance reasons and some of the assigned values can be lost during a database failure or server restart. This can result in gaps in the identity value upon insert*”.
Atenção para o trecho “This can result in gaps”!

Como solução, ainda na mesma documentação é citado que “*If gaps are not acceptable then the application should use its own mechanism to generate key values*”. Ou seja, é fato de que IDENTITY não é confiável para gerar sequências numéricas consecutivas, sem intervalos.

---

> Aprofundando no tema *gaps and islands*

Para os interessados em conhecer mais sobre o problema clássico de *gaps and islands* (intervalos e ilhas), eis alguns artigos selecionados:

- [The SQL of Gaps and Islands in Sequences](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)
- [Gaps and islands](https://www.manning.com/books/sql-server-mvp-deep-dives)  (capítulo 5 do livro SQL Server MVP Deep
  Dives)
- [Gaps and Islands… With a Twist!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/samlester/2012/09/04/tsql-solve-it-your-way-gaps-and-islands-with-a-twist/)

Comment: no código #1, tomei um 00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis" num Oracle que usei para testes...

Comment: @Dudaskank: O tópico é sobre SQL Server e as sugestões estão codificadas em T-SQL. // Para PL/SQL você deve substituir `dbo.T1` pelo nome da tabela. // Sobre o teste do código #1 no Oracle Database, conseguiu verificar em que ponto do código ocorre a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Sim, verdade José, é que eu achei interessante e queria ver a saída da query numa tabela aqui, tanto que o código #2 nem me arrisquei rs. O erro parece apontar para a linha do `rangeend`, e a mensagem completa é: Erro completo (seria na linha do rangeend): ORA-00907: parêntese direito não encontrado
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Erro na linha: 5 Coluna: 6

Comment: Mas eu olhei a query e os parênteses estão todos lá

Comment: @Dudaskank: O erro ORA-00937 refere-se ao uso da função de agregação sem a presença da cláusula GROUP BY. Vide https://techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00937.php // Encontrei tópicos em fóruns que citam situação parecida (uso de subconsulta com função de agregação mas sem cláusula GROUP BY) e como contornar.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a cláusula `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM tabela t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM tabela t2
                   WHERE t2.id -1 = t1.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Outro método, que funciona em qualquer BD:

```
SELECT
  min(id)
FROM tabela
WHERE id+1 NOT IN
  (SELECT id FROM tabela
  )
;
```

Se precisar saber todos os `id`s que não tem o próximo, basta fazer assim:

```
SELECT
  id
FROM tabela
WHERE id+1 NOT IN
  (SELECT id FROM tabela
  )
ORDER BY id;
```

Note que estas queries só pegam a partir do menor número de id pra cima. Se por exemplo os id's são 5, 6 e 8 na tabela, ele mostrará o valor 6, e não o 0, já que não possui o id 1.